# what to do with this database?

Tags: mysql

1. Add a new book to the database
   a) Capture Book name, Author, Genre (type of book) and ISBN number and store in the
   database.
   b) If same book name is added twice, the application should just increase the available
   quantity rather than adding a new book.
2. Search for a book and its availability
   a) Search should be a “like” search. All possible results should be shown.
3. View details of a selected book.
   a) After searching, let the user choose a book and view the available quantity and who has
   taken it and when it is expected to be returned.
4. Lend a book to a user.
   a) Capture the name of the user, phone number and the date on which it is expected to be
   returned.
5. Following reports
   a) List of all books that are supposed to be returned today.
   b) Count of books by genre.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a SQL fiddle where you can check the results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0ae78b/1

The table may look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
 isbn VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
  title varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  genre varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  author varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  counter INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1);
```

Of course, you need to tweak field lengths and nullability of all fields to your needs. ISBN field, as it is a primary key, cannot be nullable.

To comment on it a little bit - ISBN is a perfect primary key in this example. Every other book has a different ISBN number. Having this set up the only thing you have to remember about is to add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause in all your INSERT queries. In our case, it would be

```
INSERT INTO books (isbn, title) VALUES ('code-book-1', 'star wars'), ('code-book-1', 'star wars') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + 1;
```

Instead of returning an error with a primary key collision value in the `counter` field will be increased by one.